# Launch or introduce new product?

Tags: american-english, word-difference, british-english

If company is going to sell new product on the market and it will happened next month.
Is it better to say:

1. Our product will be introduced in the market next month.
2. Our product will be launched in the market next month.

Answer (score 1):

The second option works better as that's what marketing people tend to say (in my experience).

However, the preposition should be **on** not "in" unless that is common usage in your area – See [the discussion on this topic here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110507/in-the-market-or-on-the-market).